# How to suppress logs

Tags: go, logging

If I have a code in Go like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    log.Println("log hello world")
}
```

is it possible to run this program suppressing the log output without change the source code, passing a flag or env variable from command line like for example `QUIET=1 go run hello`?

Comment: The log package writes to stderr by default, so you can redirect that stream in your shell: `go run hello 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Interesting but weird cause a log message is not an error message.

Comment: A log message isn't productive output either. Imagine implementing grep in Go and log messages would go to stdout.

Comment: "Interesting but weird cause a log message is not an error message" -- pretty standard behavior for most unix tools, though.

Comment: [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) may help you. It also has log levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have the shell discard the output using `go run hello 2>/dev/null` (as @TimCooper mentioned in the comments), or you can overwrite the output of the `log` package by calling `log.SetOutput()` and passing an implementation of `io.Writer` that discards the input (or writes it to whatever you want).